# How to pass json array as a string to web api from postman

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, postman

My Json [Body] structure in postman is given below

```
[{
  "SerialNumber": "dev1",

  "CustomerId": "cust1",

  "Seed": "c393d900-2f25-819f-cc83-0721357bcf10",

  "BitLockerKey": null,

  "bitLockerRecoveryKey": null

   },

 {

  "SerialNumber": "dev2",

  "CustomerId": "cust2",

  "Seed": "c393d900-2f25-819f-cc83-0721357bcf22",

  "BitLockerKey": null,

  "bitLockerRecoveryKey": null

}]
```

My web api function is given below,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> SaveData([FromBody] string Data)
    {
        int result = _seedService.SeedGeneration(Data);
        return result > 0 ? Ok(result) : (ActionResult<string>)UnprocessableEntity("Seed generation 
        Failed");
    }
```

My question is, how to pass data as string with json array structure in postman. i got the error "JSON value could not be converted to System.string

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package & modified the function. removed string as parameter & included JsonElement in parameter.

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult<string> SaveData([FromBody] JsonElement Data)
{
    string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Data);
    int result = _seedService.SeedGeneration(json);
    return result > 0 ? Ok(result) : (ActionResult<string>)UnprocessableEntity("Seed 
    generation Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.stringify(jsonValue) you can convert a JSON object to string via javascript.

The result is the following:

```
"[{"SerialNumber":"dev1","CustomerId":"cust1","Seed":"c393d900-2f25-819f-cc83-0721357bcf10","BitLockerKey":null,"bitLockerRecoveryKey":null},{"SerialNumber":"dev2","CustomerId":"cust2","Seed":"c393d900-2f25-819f-cc83-0721357bcf22","BitLockerKey":null,"bitLockerRecoveryKey":null}]"
```

You can also declare the action parameter as an array of an object with the structure of your Json and the Asp.Net mechanism you handle it for you.